# How to make regex code apply only to empty target cells

Tags: python, pandas, regex

An example of my data

| StreetAddress | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Main St 01123 | Winsted | CT |  |
| 1 Main St | Winsted | CT | 01123 |

I am trying to use regex and pandas to clean a spreadsheet that I have.  The problem I am running into is that my regex code is replacing every cell in the entire column even if there is valid data in it.

I tried

```
df['Zip'] = df['StreetAddress'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')
df['StreetAddress'] = df['StreetAddress'].str.replace(r'(\d{5})', '', regex=True)
```

which gives me

| StreetAddress | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Main St | Winsted | CT | 01123 |
| 1 Main St | Winsted | CT |  |

I was hoping for something more like this

| StreetAddress | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Main St | Winsted | CT | 01123 |
| 1 Main St | Winsted | CT | 01123 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a boolean mask, this will avoid overwriting existing data, and also be more efficient since only the relevant rows will be evaluated:

```
add = df['StreetAddress'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})', expand=False)
m = add.notna()
df.loc[m, 'Zip'] = add[m]
df.loc[m, 'StreetAddress'] = (df.loc[m, 'StreetAddress']
                                .str.replace(r' *\d{5}', '', regex=True)
                             )
```

Alternatively:

```
df['Zip'] = df['StreetAddress'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})', expand=False).fillna(df['Zip'])
```

Or, as suggested by @ouroboros1, to keep the original Zip:

```
df['Zip'].fillna(df['StreetAddress'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})', expand=False))
```

Output:

```
  StreetAddress     City State    Zip
0     1 Main St  Winsted    CT  01123
1     1 Main St  Winsted    CT  01123
```

Comment: I think this assumes that you will only find a match for "StreetAddress", where "Zip" is `nan`. Suppose the second row has '1 Main St 12345', then clearly you would overwrite '01123'. E.g., the alternative should be `df['Zip'].fillna(df['StreetAddress'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})', expand=False))`, no? To be on the safe side.

Comment: @ouroboros1 that's a fair point, I indeed assumed an extracted match would correlate with an empty Zip ;)